# How to remove MySQL on boot

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, runlevel

```
denis@australia:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS \n \l

denis@australia:~$ chkconfig --list mysql
mysql                     0:off  1:off  2:off  3:off  4:off  5:off  6:off
```

But mysql runs on the startup anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing that the issue here is that checkconfig checks the old style init scripts, and you have a new upstart init script.

Go to `/etc/init/mysql.conf` and change `start on (net-device-up and local-filesystems)` to `start on runlevel [!0123456]` If you need to start it manually `service mysql start` will do the trick. [This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1501721) on ubuntu forums goes into some depth on the process

A bit more background - chkconfig works on old school init scripts - they're known as /etc/rc scripts, but the form used in ubuntu was /etc/init.d. In order to list scripts - according to [this question on AU](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1501721), the command you should be using instead of `chkconfig` is `initctl list`. It will not change runlevels for you like chkconfig would tho.

Comment: Every time I get used to how Linux handles startup, something changes, and it never gets *easier* to understand. (Sorry, nothing to do with your post, I'm just getting frustrated.)

Comment: I hear ya. For many years, init.d was *the* way. Now we also have upstart and systemd to worry about. I *only* know how to use upstart cause I had issues with it before and ended up learning it. Docs were crappier then ;p.